# how to pass input value to <s:url> call

Tags: struts2-jquery

I want to pass input area value in ***s:url*** using ***s:param*** (where I marked as 'xxx') . Here is my code

```
    <s:url id='getName' action ='getNameAction'>
       <s:param name="userName" value= 'xxx' />
    </s:url>
```

the input jsp code is

```
    <textarea id="user" name="userName" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    <sj:a id="getNameHref" href="%{getName}" targets="commands" onSuccessTopics="complete" indicator="indicator"  button="true" >Show Me</sj:a>
```

how can I pass the textarea value to ***s:param*** tag in ***s:url*** call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve it, I use ajax .getJSon() instead.